Is it possible to change border color
AL,
Is it possible to change border color of single line text control or combo box in the OSX/Cocoa app?
What I'm looking for to do:
Let's say I have a masked text control to enter some date. So initially the control will display "  /  /    ".
But when the user tries to enter wrong value , the birder if the control becomes red.
Unless OSX UI Guidelines says its not the way to indicate the input error.
Thank you.

Does this answer your question? Can I change the border color of an NSTextField?
